# Update table from another when field contains the index of second table

Tags: sql, sql-update

```
The case:
```

I have a table (300 rows) realty with these details:

```
     id     | locality| postcode| declat  | declong | alias             |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------    
     13     |         |         |         |         | bla bla wimar bla |
     14     |         |         |         |         | bla bla bla bla   |
     15     |         |         |         |         | bla bla bla arafo |
```

and other postcodes table (900 rows) with this data:

```
    locality| postcode | lat        | long
    ---------------------------------------------    
      cande | 504      | 37.9418594 | -0.7795244
      arafo | 501      | 38.9418594 | -0.7795255  
      wimar | 500      | 39.9418594 | -0.7795277
```

I need to update the rows of table realty like this:

```
      id     | locality| postcode| declat     | declong   | alias             |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
      13     |  wimar  | 500     | 39.9418594 |-0.7795277 | bla bla wimar bla |
      14     |         |         |            |           | bla bla bla bla   |
      15     |  arafo  | 501     | 38.9418594 |-0.7795255 | bla bla bla arafo |
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's about constraint between these two tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your rdbms, and if this is just a one off, you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE realty
  SET locality = p.locality
     ,postcode = p.postcode
     ,declat =  p.declat
     ,declong = p.declong
  FROM postcodes p
  WHERE alias LIKE '%' || p.locality || '%'
```

A bunch of stuff to look out for, though (scanning, duplicate matches, etc)

Comment: sorry, but WHERE alias LIKE '%' || p.locality || '%' give me a syntax error.

Comment: I ran it without error on Postgresql. What was the error? Perhaps the tables I created in the test have column name mismatches with your tables?